# How to display an image in flex with Content-Type: image/jpeg?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an .aspx page that generates thumbnails.  It takes an ID and returns an image with response Content-Type: image/jpeg.

How do I display this image in Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
<mx:Image source="http://localhost/webform.aspx?ID=1"/>
```

You can obviously set the source in ActionScript or make the URL a bindable string so that you can pass in the ID.

Comment: This approach won't quite work as described, since @Embed is a compile-time directive.  But the concept correct.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you use the `Image` tag, and provided you're setting the response headers and encoding the bytes properly on the server (and you're working within the security sandbox), you should just be able to set the `source` property of that tag (it need not be @Embed-ded), and be done:

```
<mx:Image source="http://someurl.com/myimagegenerator.php?id=123" />
```

Are you having a problem with that approach, or is it just a general-information question?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a [Loader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/)

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.yoursite.com/yourasp.aspx?img=01001"));
addChild(loader);
```